# Microsoft OData Customising ODataWriterSettings through dependency injection

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, odata

I am needing to change the odata writer settings so that when the written object does not conform to the schema it continues writing instead of throwing an error on validate of null properties that are marked as required.

Code is like the following:

```
var writerSettings = new ODataMessageWriterSettings();
writerSettings.Validations = ValidationKinds.None;
```

I need the Microsoft.AspNetCore OData Message Writer to use those settings. But when the ODataMessageWriter is instantiated it doesn't have these settings.
When I debug and put a break point in ODataMessageWriter constructor I can change settings and get the needed results.

```
writerSettings.Validations = ValidationKinds.ThrowOnDuplicatePropertyNames | ValidationKinds.ThrowOnUndeclaredPropertyForNonOpenType; // This is the desired setting.
```

I noticed we have the following class defined and injected,

```
public class MyODataRoutingApplicationModelProvider : IApplicationModelProvider
{
    public MyODataRoutingApplicationModelProvider(
        IOptions<ODataOptions> options)
    {
        options.Value.AddRouteComponents("odata/{datasource}/{COMPANY_CODE}", EdmCoreModel.Instance);
    }
```

Do I need to alter this model provider to make it use those settings?

The following exception is the initial problem that i were trying to solve. Changing the data layer  / edm model/ schema does not seem a possible option that we want thats specific to our solution / database schema.

Microsoft.OData.ODataException: The property 'ImpArrivalDate[Nullable=False]' of type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset' has a null value, which is not allowed.
at Microsoft.OData.WriterValidationUtils.ValidateNullPropertyValue(IEdmTypeReference expectedPropertyTypeReference, String propertyName, IEdmModel model)
at Microsoft.OData.WriterValidator.ValidateNullPropertyValue(IEdmTypeReference expectedPropertyTypeReference, String propertyName, Boolean isTopLevel, IEdmModel model)
at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertySerializer.WriteNullProperty(ODataPropertyInfo property)
at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertySerializer.WriteProperty(ODataProperty property, IEdmStructuredType owningType, Boolean isTopLevel, IDuplicatePropertyNameChecker duplicatePropertyNameChecker, ODataResourceMetadataBuilder metadataBuilder)
at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertySerializer.WriteProperties(IEdmStructuredType owningType, IEnumerable`1 properties, Boolean isComplexValue, IDuplicatePropertyNameChecker duplicatePropertyNameChecker, ODataResourceMetadataBuilder metadataBuilder)
at Microsoft.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightWriter.StartResource(ODataResource resource)
at Microsoft.OData.ODataWriterCore.<>c__DisplayClass123_0.b__0()

The property is marked as required but as nullable as shown in the extended class (ConsignmentAllHeaderXpo):

```
[XmlIgnore]
        [Delayed]
        [PersistentAlias("ShipmentDate")]
        [Template(typeof(HardDate1))]
        [Display(Name = "Arr.Date", Description = "Import Arrival Date")]
        [Description("Import Arrival Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field Arr.Date is required")]
        [RpsHelp(Text = "Expected Arrival Date")]
        public DateTime? ImpArrivalDate
        {
            get { return GetValue<DateTime?>(null, nameof(ImpArrivalDate)); }
            set { ShipmentDate = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImpArrivalDate)); }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that changing the writer settings that I need to use when processing the request as shown here in the controller's action has worked:

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 1000)]
public IActionResult Get([FromRoute] string COMPANY_CODE)
{
    // Get entity set's EDM type: A collection type.
    ODataPath path = Request.ODataFeature().Path;
    IEdmCollectionType collectionType = (IEdmCollectionType)path.Last().EdmType;
    
    IEdmEntityTypeReference entityType = collectionType.ElementType.AsEntity();

    // Setting validation settings on the request to not throw when writing a json response representation is solving the problem.
    // It stops validation errors occuring if the data does not conform to the schema.
    Request.GetWriterSettings().Validations = Microsoft.OData.ValidationKinds.ThrowOnDuplicatePropertyNames | Microsoft.OData.ValidationKinds.ThrowOnUndeclaredPropertyForNonOpenType;
    string myType = entityType.ShortQualifiedName();
    Type xpoType = DataAccess.GetNameSpaceType(myType);
    var res = GetIQueryable(xpoType, COMPANY_CODE, false);
    return Ok(res);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering, you can can change the settings globally by injecting them into the route service provider on OData configuration like so:

```
builder.Services.AddMvc(...).AddOData((options, s) => {
    options.AddRouteComponents("odata", odataModel, s => {
        s.AddSingleton<ODataMessageWriterSettings>(_ => new ODataMessageWriterSettings{
            Validations = Microsoft.OData.ValidationKinds.ThrowOnDuplicatePropertyNames | Microsoft.OData.ValidationKinds.ThrowOnUndeclaredPropertyForNonOpenType
        });
    });
});
```